# Java how to know who is modifying a ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there a way to print out who was modifing an `ArrayList` at the moment of a `ConcurrentModificationException` on `Iterator.next()`?

Comment: Not really.  I would suggest either keeping arrays to a single thread or look for a thread-safe alternative.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample and exception stack?

Comment: Isn't the stack trace enough to determine that? Is you application multithreaded?

Comment: @C.Champagne No it isn't. The exception is thrown when a concurrent modification has been *detected*, not when it occurs.

Comment: Basically *you* are modifying it, possibly by incorrectly combining iterating with deletion or insertion. Post some code.

Comment: I have just upvoted this question, cause it made me laugh. Who was modifying it? I bet it was you!

Comment: @EJP Oops sorry! You're right. It is obviously too late at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

If this is only for debugging and temporary trouble shooting, I can suggest using a dynamic `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`. This will work if you control the creation of the `ArrayList`. Using the proxy you can intercept the iterator creation an create a proxy for it as well.

Basically, add logging before and after each method the proxy intercepts. Then you can analyze the log to see what was the flow of method invocations.
To learn how to create proxies, there are lots of great blogs and examples, but I suggest you start with the [Java Reflection Guide at Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html). There is an example there very similar to what you need.

HTH.

**UPDATE:** Of course proxies can be used only with interfaces, i.e. only if you don't strictly refer to `ArrayList` in your code (except for instantiating it). Otherwise you'll need to refactor your code to use `List` in declarations instead of `ArrayList`...

Comment: `ArrayList` is a concrete class. You cannot create proxies directly with it. The code must be adapted tu use interfaces instead (such as `List` in this case)

Comment: @C.Champagne You are correct, my assumption was he's using `List` interface for declarations but instantiating an `ArrayList`. I failed to mention this assumption.

Comment: You can extend `ArrayList` for similar effect.

Comment: IMHO, extending `ArrayList` is much more work, more verbose and error-prone in this case.

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc for `ArrayList` (my emphasis):

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, ***the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException***.

So it is the accessing iterator that throws the exception, not the modifying thread.  You may not find out about the modification at the time it occurs, and the CME will occur only when you attempt to advance or fetch a value through an existing iterator.

If you must detect the *modification* operation you will probably have to wrap the implementation.